# Motion of opposite electric charges

Tags: electrostatics, singularities, coulombs-law

I have what seems like an obvious question, but I have gotten a completely paradoxical answer to it. My goal is to understand what would happen if two particles with opposite charges $q_1$ and $-q_2$ and masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ were placed a distance $s$ apart. It seems obvious, to start with, that the charges will be attracted to each other and accelerate until they collide. My question is: what speed will they be going as they reach each other? The formula for potential energy of two charges,$$V=-\frac{q_1q_2}{r_{12}},$$implies that the energy goes from a finite negative number to $-\infty$ by the time the two charges collide, which implies that they should be moving with infinite velocity. This seems ridiculous, however, which leads me to wonder: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *moving with infinite velocity* That is the correct classical *non-relativistic* result. It’s not correct if you take Special Relativity into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the particles get close enough that the distance between them is roughly on the order of the size of the particles themselves, it no longer becomes a good approximation to say they are both "point charges", and thus the above equation no longer works.

To solve those problems, you actually need to go beyond the classical realm of physics and use quantum mechanics or quantum field theory.

The short of it is no, they don't go to infinite velocity, they undergo Bhabba Scattering